# How to access data from this array file using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

This is the data using `var_export($result);`

```
 array ( 0 => array ( 'album' => array ( 'album_type' => 'ALBUM', 'artists' => array ( 0 => array ( 'external_urls' => array ( 'spotify' => 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6rBvjnvdsRxFRSrq1StGOM', ), 'href' => 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6rBvjnvdsRxFRSrq1StGOM', 'id' => '6rBvjnvdsRxFRSrq1StGOM', 'name' => 'Bathory', 'type' => 'artist', 'uri' => 'spotify:artist:6rBvjnvdsRxFRSrq1StGOM', ), ), 'external_urls' => array ( 'spotify' => 'https://open.spotify.com/album/1ZN0dVt3JGTUJZ5TydY1E8', ), 'href' => 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1ZN0dVt3JGTUJZ5TydY1E8', 'id' => '1ZN0dVt3JGTUJZ5TydY1E8', 'images' => array ( 0 => array ( 'height' => 640, 'url' => 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ba052dff3d3cf0f5bd9b66a7ac707c2f4dfad065', 'width' => 640, ), 1 => array ( 'height' => 300, 'url' => 'https://i.scdn.co/image/20b02fb5aae2cfe790adb6b65433850a0977542c', 'width' => 300, ), 2 => array ( 'height' => 64, 'url' => 'https://i.scdn.co/image/668e5fb3a1044d4a2d7a90d3491612fe702d558b', 'width' => 64, ), ), 'name' => 'Blood Fire Death', 'type' => 'album', 'uri' => 'spotify:album:1ZN0dVt3JGTUJZ5TydY1E8', ), 'artists' => array ( 0 => array ( 'external_urls' => array ( 'spotify' => 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6rBvjnvdsRxFRSrq1StGOM', ), 'href' => 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6rBvjnvdsRxFRSrq1StGOM', 'id' => '6rBvjnvdsRxFRSrq1StGOM', 'name' => 'Bathory', 'type' => 'artist', 'uri' => 'spotify:artist:6rBvjnvdsRxFRSrq1StGOM', ), ), 'disc_number' => 1, 'duration_ms' => 220200, 'explicit' => false, 'external_ids' => array ( 'isrc' => 'SEXHQ8800404', ), 'external_urls' => array ( 'spotify' => 'https://open.spotify.com/track/0i6joqNGcGa73MXEi1qVJi', ), 'href' => 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/0i6joqNGcGa73MXEi1qVJi', 'id' => '0i6joqNGcGa73MXEi1qVJi', 'is_playable' => true, 'name' => 'Pace Till Death', 'popularity' => 28, 'preview_url' => 'https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/572b24bf4fae0a7ce5ef835b5dc5c60826c4bc79?cid=24974f52d3fc4029a03bee338698b062', 'track_number' => 4, 'type' => 'track', 'uri' => 'spotify:track:0i6joqNGcGa73MXEi1qVJi', ), )
```

How do I access this part of the current file below

```
[images] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [height] => 640 [url] => https://i.scdn.co/image/f57171446c8d61050af0e43726c4863dfdc235a4 [width] => 640 ) [1] => Array ( [height] => 300 [url] => https://i.scdn.co/image/4111d12bb7e3a142d12309ba699ce97d78fd8905
```

Using PHP how do I display this data above I've tried the below which retrieves the name, however, I want the image as shown above. Note that $result is where I store the results from the API

```
$result = json_decode(json_encode($result), true);

foreach($result as $obj){

   echo "Name : " . $obj['name'];
}
```

Comment: Isn't this [basic array accessing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing)?

Comment: Can you add to outcome of `var_export($result);`?

Comment: Would this be easier , if I turned it into json format? how may I do this?

Comment: @Thefourthbird the var_export($result) is the same as the data above in my question detials

Comment: @John That is true, but [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) has the advantage the returned representation is valid PHP code and makes it easier to help you.

Comment: ok I will attach it to my question now @Thefourthbird

Comment: @John If you want the 'images' array, try it like this: `foreach($result as $obj){
    print_r($obj['album']['images']);
}`

Comment: @John Out of curiosity,  how can `$result[0]['external_urls']['images'][0]['url']` be correct?

Comment: It retrieves the data I want to use. i then echo it and since its an image , i can use <img> and use php indentation to use the below array path. Your is also correct sorry , I just didn't see it and gives more detail thanks apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images array is not located at the `['name']` key, but you can access the data using `['album']['images']`:

For example:

```
foreach ($result as $obj) {
    print_r($obj['album']['images']);
    echo $obj['album']['images'][0]['url'];
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/v6Oqh)

Comment: this is correct , apologies again. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

if I understand it correctly you want access multi dimmed array.
Try like this one to access a field from your $result array:

$result[0]['album']['images'][0]['url']

This would return "https://i.scdn.co/image/ba052dff3d3cf0f5bd9b66a7ac707c2f4dfad065"

$result[0]['album']['images'][1]['url'] ==> "https://i.scdn.co/image/20b02fb5aae2cfe790adb6b65433850a0977542c"

$result[0]['album']['images'][2]['url'] ==> "https://i.scdn.co/image/668e5fb3a1044d4a2d7a90d3491612fe702d558b"